# Which characters should be omitted from a URL so that it doesn't get encoded? (i.e. more human readable)

Tags: regex, url

I initially had a function with a regex which removed all non alphanumeric characters and _ and that worked fine, as intended.

```golang
func titleToURL(title string) string {
    threadURL := strings.Replace(title, " ", "_", -1)
    pattern := regexp.MustCompile(`[^a-zA-Z\d_]`)
    threadURL = pattern.ReplaceAllString(threadURL, "")
    if len(threadURL) > urlMax {
        threadURL = threadURL[0:urlMax]
    }
    return threadURL
}
```

But, I later wanted the URL to have utf-8 characters like 香港, etc. So I removed the regex replace so that such characters would be allowed in. But after that, when a character like [ or ] gets passed, the URL shows all these % symbols and whatnot. I want these URLs to be human readable since they are not for passing data.

In short, I want URLs to look like `text_test_url` or `chinese_香港` and not `%3F_%5BM%5D`

Which characters should I remove to achieve this? Provide a regex if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding) lists the characters that get percent-encoded:

- `:`
- `/`
- `?`
- `#`
- `[`
- `]`
- `@`
- `!`
- `$`
- `&`
- `` ` ``
- `(`
- `)`
- `*`
- `+`
- `,`
- `;`
- `=`
- `%`

So your regex would just check for those characters (escaping them as necessary).